# Split fillePath and filename using matcher and pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Hi i wanted to group filepath and filename from given string value.

e.g. `com/abc/chilkatsoft/CkEmail1$.class`

```
filePath = com/abc/chilkatsoft
fileName = CkEmail1$.class
```

I tried with `(.*?)?(\\/.+)` but its spiting first occurrence of '/'.
Can any-buddy help me on this.

Actually I wanted parse log file data i had completed 80%. i.e.

```
45013 Thu Aug 15 19:42:38 IST 2013 com/chilkatsoft/CkEmail.class
```

Comment: If you want to use a regex for this, it would be [`(.+)/(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/DbHpYL/1)

Comment: any reason to use regex instead of .... lets say **indexOf**   ???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I think you meant `lastIndexOf('/')`, right?

Comment: jap... why regex is my question????

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : thanks its works awesome man. Actually i wanted parse log file data i had completed 80%.  i.e. "45013 Thu Aug 15 19:42:38 IST 2013 com/chilkatsoft/CkEmail.class" and i used "^([\\d]+) ([\\w:/\\s{5}]+) (.+)/(.+)"  now.

Comment: This pattern is not correct. Why did you use `\\s{5}`? Please post the real log line into the question to show real formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are parsing log lines and the data you need to match occupies almost the whole line, it is possible to use greedy dot matching patterns.

```
^(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(.+)/(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ7ADq/2)

Here,

- `^`  - a string/line start
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (replace with a regular space if you use multiline modifier)
- `(.*)` - Group 2 capturing the whole rest of the line up to the final whitespace
- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `(.+)` - any 0+ chars up to the last `/`
- `/` - a slash
- `(.+)` - the rest of the line.

To make the pattern more explicit, spell out the patterns inside:

```
^(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4})\s+(.+)/(.+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ7ADq/1)